# php - Create an array of type boolean

Tags: php

So I can do
`array(Type::NUMBER=>1)`, and I can do `array(Type::STRING=>"one")`

But how do I do `array(Type::BOOLEAN=>true)`

True, I can just use numbers, and input either a 0 or a 1, but I figured I'd check to see if there was a way I can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP Docs:

> The key can either be an integer or a string. *The value can be of any type.*

(Emphasis mine)

[PHP: Arrays - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

For example:

```
$array = array(
           "key1" => true,
           "key2" => false,
           "key3" => false,
           "key4" => true
         );
```

Comment: So it has to be either one of those two? Thanks

Comment: The `key` can be either an integer or string, but the `value` can be anything.